# Distribute open source project via Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, open-source, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio Team Services (visualstudio.com) for all of my source control. I would like to make a couple of my projects open source and grant public access to download the source. Does anyone know if there is a way to configure a Visual Studio Team Services project to facilitate this? Specifically, I would need a way to grant read access to everyone, but keep write access restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, this is not possible, but I created a UserVoice request for it.  So if you want it, go and vote for it.

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3701461-in-team-foundation-service-allow-projects-to-be-

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can grant access to "everyone". I don't believe there *is* a concept of "everyone" in the hosted system.

Answer (score 0):

As [discerns says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099150/6438), this is not possible right now.  [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com) would be the thing to use for Open Source projects based on TFS.

Comment: Hi Martin, the issue with Codeplex is the lack of Build. The main reason I like TFService is the ability to use the full TFS build system.

Comment: Understood - I'll pass along the feedback.